# non thread specific IDisposable based ReaderWriterLock

Tags: .net, async-await

I'm looking for resource protection like `ReaderWriterLock` which blocks the thread on `Enter` but doesn't rely that `Release/Exit` is called on the very same thread. I instead would prefer an `IDisposable` based release/exit method. (Lock elevation from Reading to Writing is not required at all).

I already have wrapped a `ReaderWriterLock` with an `IDisposable` accessor which works fine as long there is no async-await pattern involved. When I use it with async-await in a server context (ASP.NET Web Api) then even a simple `using` block calls `Dispose()` on another thread if there is an `await` inside the using block.

Is anyone aware of a class (Framework or NuGet) which is capable of such Multi-Read-Single-Write locking?

Comment: "Is anyone aware of a class (Framework or NuGet) which is capable of such Multi-Read-Single-Write locking?" `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is designed **exactly** for this purpose. I think your question should be how to implement this in an asynchronous environment?

Comment: @aevitas From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): `ReaderWriterLockSlim has managed thread affinity; that is, each Thread object must make its own method calls to enter and exit lock modes.`, so I think you have Exit in the thread you Enter

Comment: [Building Async Coordination Primitives, Part 7: AsyncReaderWriterLock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-7-asyncreaderwriterlock.aspx).

Comment: @xanatos Exactly, which I why I suggested adding the multi-threaded requirement to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

- Here's how you can implement your own: [Building Async Coordination Primitives, Part 7: AsyncReaderWriterLock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-7-asyncreaderwriterlock.aspx)
- Here's Stephen Cleary's: [AsyncEx\AsyncReaderWriterLock](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncReaderWriterLock)
- Here's a version by MS which is a part of the VS SDK: [AsyncReaderWriterLock\AsyncReaderWriterLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asyncreaderwriterlock.aspx)

Comment: +1. But I am compelled to point out that the complexity of a RWL is almost never necessary, even when the methods do have reader/writer semantics. A plain SemaphoreSlim/AsyncLock is simpler and suffices for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

> Is anyone aware of a class (Framework or NuGet) which is capable of such Multi-Read-Single-Write locking?

I found this nuget: `Singulink.Threading.ReadWriteGuard`

Project URL with examples:
https://github.com/Singulink/Singulink.Threading.ReadWriteGuard

It has extension methods which converts the ReaderWriterLockSlim to observable.